# Tailwind CSS Classes are not being applied in React App

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I followed the article https://medium.com/@rsrofficial99/react-vite-tailwind-6238209f95ad to create a react app using vite and tailwind css.

Here is my folder structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IojMf.png)

Here is my Package Json:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvMrd.png)

Here is my tailwind config file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

And here is my postcss:

```
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss';
export const plugins = [
    tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.cjs'),
    require('autoprefixer')
];
```

I have also included

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

in my index.css. But the tailwind classes are not being applied. Ive tried to reinstall and upgrade everything, but notthing seems to work.

I tried reinstalling the project.

Comment: Refer the official [tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite) docs for installing. It has great documentation for all the frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Please follow steps from the [official docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite) it will work just fine.

If it doesn't work after following above mentioned official docs, Please edit your question to contain the `App.jsx` `index.css` `tailwind.config.cjs`, Stack overflow community will help you out!